# error in dynamic memory allocation from within a global variable

Tags: c++

Here is description of my problem:

- There is a class "Class_A", which needs 1076 byte of memory for a construction of
  its instance.

> sizeof(Class_A) = 1076 bytes;

- There is a wrapper class for Class_A, "Class_A_Wrapper", which dynamically creates an  instance of "Class_A" in its constructor:

.

```
#include "Class_A.h"
Class_A_Wrapper{
  public:
     Class_A_Wrapper();                                            
     ~Class_A_Wrapper();  
  private:
     Class_A* class_a;                                    
};

Class_A_Wrapper::Class_A_Wrapper(){
  class_a = new Class_A();  
}
```

- Class_A_Wrapper object is declared globally in a third file:

.

```
#include "Class_A_Wrapper.h"

Class_A_Wrapper a_wrapper;
```

- Program crash!

Program crashes before the "main"-function call, at the moment, when it tries to create
the "a_wrapper"-object, calls constructor for Class_A_Wrapper and finally calls "class_a = new Class_A()"; for reasons, which I don't understand, the compiler evaluates the sizeof(Class_A) as 1044 bytes, not 1076 as it should. 
This is not my code, this is not me, who declares objects globally in third files,but I need to find the reason for this crash and I am really puzzled.
I would be very grateful for any comments and hints, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If Class_A is in a shared library, make sure that the headers you use for linking are for the same versions that is loaded at runtime

Comment: show us the constructor of class_A and how did you know that it allocated 1044 bytes

Comment: I pasted your code into a source file and added the minimum amount of code to make it compile (a definition of `Class_A`, an empty implementation for `Class_A_Wrapper`'s destructor, an empty `main`). It ran fine for me. Perhaps your problem is with some code that you haven't posted?

Comment: probably try it out in a debugger.

Comment: Constructor of Class_A initializes a lot of variables (primitive types as well as complex objects), I have checked its total size by calling sizeof from a testing method. Borland Builder's Code Guard also tells me that this object has a size of 1076 byte and only 1044 bytes were allocated.

Comment: Check in `Class_A` constructor for the pointer members, which you might be using it without `new` ing..

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once; it was caused by different compilation options for source file 2 and the one that defined `Class_A` constructor. In my case, the different options affected the size of enums (1 byte vs 4 bytes), so the `new` call allocated e.g. 1044 bytes but `Class_A` constructor initialized e.g. 1076 bytes.

There are other differences in compilation options that can matter (e.g. size of pointers, struct-packing options, maybe even some members of `Class_A` are declared using conditional compilation, i.e. `#ifdef`).

I am certainly not sure this is what happened in your case; just sharing my experience.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. The problem is, that the same crash happens under gcc on Linux, where it is easier to check compilation options and they seem to be the same. But I will check it once again now... (My other compiler is Borland Builder, which can really lead to an easy confusion in compilation options...)

Comment: @Yuliana check in Class_A declaraction if it has some #ifdef hiding some members

Comment: But I compile all the files simultaneously, so it something is defined, it is defined - or not?

Comment: @Yuliana Having the same possibility in mind, another idea for debugging could be: replace `new Class_A()` with `new Class_A[2]` to get rid of the crash, and print out all member variables of `class_a[0]` after construction. You will probably see unexpected values, which can help you find the problem.

Comment: THANK YOU EVERYONE for the help and especially Dmitry Yudakov, it were wrong headers indeed (even without using a library). I have found one hidden in one of the subdirectories, it was included first during the compilation and gave a wrong constructor size. Дмитрий, спасибо большое!